# Google Drive integration with private website

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to integrate Google Drive with my private website in such way that user will provide my website with his own Google Drive, and he could perform on my website such actions as: viewing, deleting, adding or editing files. Is is possible? What is needed to do such integration?

I read Google Drive API documentation and I checked it is possible to perform such actions as creating, reading, editing files. But I have no idea how to perform it on someones else private Google Drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is that drive api is a rest api the response is returned in Json format. The google drive api is not going to give you any visual representation of a users drive account.  For example your not going to be able to show them the google drive web application from your website.  You will need to code the interface yoruself.

As for how to get permission we use something called Oauth2 to request consent for your application to access the users google drive account.  It can be a little confusing in the beginning but there are a number of tutorials and QuickStart's which should help you get started.

Comment: Thank you! Can non GCP user obtain OAuth 2.0 token? Or the only way is through Google Cloud Console?

Comment: You create an app on Google cloud console, then your app will be able to request consent of a user.